# Imagem subindo com html5 no crossfade

Tags: html5

Tenho esse código html5 que faz a transição de imagens, o que preciso é fazer com que a imagem fique subindo e descendo dentro de uma div e depois fazer a transição das imagens. Como poderia fazer isso?

```css
#crossfade > img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s; 
}

#crossfade > img:nth-child(2)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<div id="crossfade">
  <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5145/5576437826_940f2db110.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3611/3463265789_586ce40aef.jpg" alt="Image 2">
  <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5263/5601183065_f88a48d599.jpg" alt="Image 3">
  <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1415/983021323_8eb2f92c01.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/168/397834706_6a46c6ada5.jpg" alt="Image 1">
</div>
```

Exemplo de como eu preciso pode ver neese link

http://www.guiacatalao.com.br/empresa/maccherroni-massas-e-chopp,TmpjNU1nPT0.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As imagens começam de baixo para cima, ou seja o `nth-5` está pos cima do `nth-4` etc então o `delay` tem que ser feito de forma reversa como vc vai ver no código.

No mais eu usei `transform:translateY()` para fazer a imagem subir e o `opacity` para controlar a transparência.

**OBS:** se a imagem for mais alta do que larga ela vai passar mais rápido que as outras, então seria interessante ter todas as imagem com a mesma altura.

Veja como ficou com 5 imagens.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#crossfade {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#crossfade > img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 10s linear infinite ;
            animation: imageAnimation 10s linear infinite ;
}

#crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
          animation-delay: 6s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
          animation-delay: 8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
              transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    16% { 
      opacity: 1;
    }
    22% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-20%); 
              transform: translateY(-20%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
              transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
              transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    16% { 
      opacity: 1;
    }
    22% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-20%); 
              transform: translateY(-20%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
              transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="crossfade">
  <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5145/5576437826_940f2db110.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3611/3463265789_586ce40aef.jpg" alt="Image 2">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/600/600" alt="Image 3">
  <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1415/983021323_8eb2f92c01.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/168/397834706_6a46c6ada5.jpg" alt="Image 1">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Opção com 3 imagens, repare que é preciso ajustar os valores da total da animação, que mudei de 10s (5 intervalos de 2s), para 6s (3 intervalos de 2s), E mudei os @keyframes para fazer a transição entre 26% e 33% e não entre 16% e 22%, pois agora preciso dividir o tempo em 3 (3x33%) e não em 5(5x20%) para ter o tempo total da animação entende...

Veja como ficou.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#crossfade {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#crossfade > img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 6s linear infinite ;
            animation: imageAnimation 6s linear infinite ;
}


#crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
              transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    16% { 
      opacity: 1;
    }
    22% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-20%); 
              transform: translateY(-20%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
              transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
              transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    26% { 
      opacity: 1;
    }
    36% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-20%); 
              transform: translateY(-20%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% { 
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
              transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="crossfade">
  <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5145/5576437826_940f2db110.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3611/3463265789_586ce40aef.jpg" alt="Image 2">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/600/600" alt="Image 3">
</div>
```

Comment: como eu faria com 3 imagens, estou fazendo aqui mais depois que acaba o loop fica em branco um tempo http://jsfiddle.net/c5kjftb7/

Comment: Cara fiz uma edição no final da minha resposta. Olha lá que vai ficar mais fácil pra vc entender. Mas vc tem que "casar" o tempo total da animação com as transições no @keyframes

Comment: não consegui entender a lógica ainda, como ficaria se eu colocasse a animação para 8s ao invés de 6s?

Comment: Vc pode ir testando o tempo, mudando de 6 para 8 e ver se vai dar alguma falha na interpolação das imagens no slider. Se der problema vc vai precisar ajustar os valores nos keyframes... Mas para 8s 4imagens ficaria perfeito, com 2s por img e delay de 2s entre cada uma, e animação em 25%, 1/4 de 100%. Testar e errar faz parte do aprendizado, então vai testando que uma hora vc entende a dinâmica